# Not able to run the app in Android Studio. Getting Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8614', transport: 'socket'"

Tags: localhost

I have started using Andriod Studio recently. I was able to run the apps initially. But after some time I am getting an error like this when i Debug the app

Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8614', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8614', transport: 'socket'

The AVD is getting launched, But this error is coming when I open the app after unlocking the screen. I have searched in stackoverflow website for some fix. But none of them is working for me.

I tried once by uninstalling and re-installing the studio. After that it was working fine for sometime. Now again I am facing this issue. Can someont please help me on this.